# Avoiding overflow with large numbers when using Mod

Tags: vba, excel

I began toying with project euler.

I have completed problem #3, but I was only able to complete it by setting my endNumber to 71 * 486847 (manually calculated). When trying to set endNumber = 600851475143 I receive the overflow error.

I even set endNumber as Long, and even Double which I think should be plenty of digits to calculate.

I can't post the whole code here, so I'll post half in hopes someone can show me how to edit it in order to process larger numbers.

Also I noticed that "#" pops up when my code has a very large number like below.

```
endNumber = 600851475143#
        countFactor = 0

        For i = 2 To endNumber
            If endNumber Mod i = 0 Then
```

Comment: What data types did you declare endNumber and i as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overflow isn't due to assigning the number `600851475143` to the `Double` variable it is that the `Mod` function does not seem to handle numbers longer than `Long` very well (in fact seemingly not at all).

An alternative can be to use the manual calc for `Mod`:

```
endNumber = 600851475143#
        countFactor = 0

        For i = 2 To endNumber
            If endNumber - (Int(endNumber / i) * i) = 0 Then
```

If you are going to use `Mod` for large numbers on a regular basis then [Chip Pearson's function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ModFunction.aspx) would be a useful one (which is where I learnt about this subject matter in the first place). It is posted as a problem in `Excel` but works perfectly in `Access`.

Comment: After looking at debug, I was getting hung up on that line where mod was.  I didn't think to look into the limits of mod.  That alternative worked, and in order to speed it up I changed the first line to...For i = 2 To Round(sqr(endNumber)) since this is a prime number question. Solved instantly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I was very tempted to give you a hint on the `sqr` part but thought better of it given the intentions of Project Euler (I've done some of the problems myself, this one included).

Comment: It came to me after doing the problem in regards to the 10,001st prime number. That was taking too long and the sqr cut that time down significantly. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The highest possible number to work with in a long is: `2.147.483.647`
A Double is for decimal purposes, so thats not what you are looking for.

The # that pops up is because a number is to large to be shown inside that cell.

Also I don't know what you want to do with that loop. But that one is going to take a very long while to run.

on this link you can find about handling large numbers: [Large Number Arithmetic](http://tushar-mehta.com/misc_tutorials/project_euler/LargeNumberArithmetic.htm)

Hope that helps